# How to get HTTP status code of a page opened in a webview in Electron

Tags: electron

I want to open a remote web app in electron's webview, but this app is sometimes down and return 503 response. The problem is that I can't detect any HTTP errors from electron, so that I can do something about it from my side.

Here is a sample of my code :

```js
        webviewObj = document.createElement('webview');
        webviewObj.addEventListener('did-fail-load', (e) => {
            // Is not fired for HTTP errors
        });

        webviewObj.addEventListener('did-finish-load', (e) => {
            // No info about HTTP status code
        });

        webviewObj.src = "https://web-app.com";
```

In an old version of electron, the webview had an event `did-get-response-details` that gives `httpResponseCode`, but it got deprecated, and I could not find an alternative.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this API https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-navigate

```js
win.webContents.on('did-navigate', (_event: any, _url: string, httpResponseCode: number) => {
    if (httpResponseCode >= 400) {
      // what you want to do
    }
  });
```